# Wrong image path updating from prestashop 1.4 to 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After two intense days of messing with Prestashop, I'm facing a problem, and my numerous searches gave nothing.

I have to update a prestashop ver. 1.4 to 1.6. Once I updated, product images won't show :
the website is looking for a path like this `src="http://siteurl.com/86-home_default/arbre-a-chat-amelia.jpg`...

But on our server, files are using another structure : `http://siteurl.com/img/p/8/6/` etc...

I tried with and without "legacy mode" (*I can't modify php safe mode*). There's no sign of any "move" option in prestashop 1.6 admin, and tricks to made this button appear (on 1.5) won't work.

Is there any way to edit how images are found? After trying to update from scratch again and again, is this safer to "just" update to 1.5.x, and then 1.6?

I'm sorry if there is only few elements here, but any help is much appreciated and I'll do my best to explain missing points if needed.

Comment: Did you regenerate thumbnails in `Preferences` -> `Images`?

Comment: Yup, but it returns an error, saying that images can't be found...

Comment: Desactivate your friendly URL, and try to regenerate your images. What exactly is your error (apache error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow urls were broken, maybe from too much legacy mode switching... Neither friendly URL desactivation or image regeneration worked.

Managed to "workaround" this by copying an old backup on wamp, in order to have safe_mode off... Then, this "move images" button was here, and totally functionnal, with image regeneration and all I needed (I don't know why I haven't thought about it earlier...).

Thanks for your support !

Answer (score 2):

I had got the same problem but updating from 1.4 to 1.5. My problem was that the new template of 1.5 uses images in this way *_default (home_default, small_default, etc). When I updated the images weren't shown because the path referenced was wrong. The solution for me was add "_default" in Preferences -> Images to every image type and then click in Regenerate images.